# A question on polynomial (Divide a polynomial function)

Tags: polynomials

When a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-2),$ the remainder is $7$. When $f(x)$ is divided by $(x+1)$ the remainder is $-2$.

(a) If the remainder is $px+q$ when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-2)(x+1)$, find the values of $p$ and $q$.

(b) Find the remainder when $f(x+3)$ is divided by $(x+1)(x+4)$

I found the values of $p$ and $q$ which are $3$ and $1$ by using remainder theorem.
 $f(x)=Q(x)*(x-2)(x+1)+(px+q)$

However I don't know how to get the remainder of part(b).

Let $g(x)=f(x+3)$.
When $g(x)$ is divided by $(x+1)$, the remainder
$=g(-1)$
$=f(-1+3)$
$=f(2)$

When $g(x)$ is divided by $(x+4)$, the remainder
$=g(-4)$
$=f(-4+3)$
$=f(-1)$

At this point, since the two remainders I got are the same when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-2)$ and $(x+1)$, 
I assume $f(x+3)=Q(x)*(x+1)(x+4)+(px+q)$.
But $3x+1$ is not the answer.
What mistakes have I made and how to solve part(b)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a lot more help if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Just replace $x$ by $x+3$ in the equation that you got in the first part. It becomes $f(x+3)=Q(x+3)(x+1)(x+4)+p(x+3)+q$. Since the degree of $p(x+3)+q$ is smaller than the degree of $(x+1)(x+4)$, then the remainder of dividing $f(x+3)$ by $(x+1)(x+4)$ is $p(x+3)+q$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ Simply shift $\,x\to x\!+\!3\,$ in the prior division with remainder, i.e.

**Lemma**  $\,\ f(x\!+\!a)\bmod g(x\!+\!a)\, = \,(f\bmod g)(x\!+\!a)$

**Proof** $\,\ f = gh + r,\ \deg r < \deg g,\ \ r = (f\bmod g),\ $ by Euclidean Division wtih Remainder

hence   $\ f(x\!+\!a) = g(x\!+\!a)h(x\!+\!a) + r(x\!+\!a),\,\ \deg r(x\!+\!a) = \deg r < \deg g  =\deg g(x\!+\!a)$

therefore $\  f(x\!+\!a)\bmod g(x\!+\!a) \,=\, r(x\!+\!a)\ $ by the *uniqueness* of the remainder.

**Remark** $ $ Your argument doesn't work because - though the remainders are the same - they are at *different* (shifted) points, i.e. $\,g(-1) = f(2) =7\,$ and $\, g(-4) = f(-1) = -2,\,$ i.e. the line $\, r(x+3)\,$ is a shifted version of the line $\,r(x) = 3x+1\,$  While they take the same values at the corresponding shifted points, they are different lines.